# How to add UIImage in MKMapView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview

I want to add a UIImage in MKMapview.

i.e.: One a particular location, I want to add an image called "apple.jpg".

I don't know how to do that.

As I have already added a draggable pin as an annotation. But I don't know if I can add multiple images or not.

Comment: i guess you are asking how to do a custom MKAnnotationView, is it so?

Comment: No. I want to simply add an image not Annotation. i.e. I want to add a picture of an apple at given location.

Comment: whatever geolocated thing in MapKit is an Annotation and its visual representation is MKAnnotationView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For add image as a Part of MKMapView see this Tutorial...

[i.ndigo mkmapview](http://i.ndigo.com.br/tag/mkmapview/)

and for add Image as a Pin on MapView then use this bellow code...

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] init];

annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];
annotationView.annotation = annotation;
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView.tag = 101;

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
 [yourMapView addAnnotation:annotationView];
```

Comment: I have tried this code. But once I pinch/zoom in or out that image remains same. I want an image to be the part of map.

Comment: means you not want to image as a pinview but as a location in MapView ??

Comment: Yes. 100% correct Paras. I am not getting any code or help or even API to do that.

Comment: Yes. It seems having my answer. I'll try to implement the feature as explained in the link.

Comment: also implement drawRect method from this tutorial and edit with your Requirement...

Answer (score 2):

as @Kassem Bagher mentions, you need to create custom `MKAnnotationView` , check whatever tutorial ([example](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=81))

Comment: I hope this example will work as i have found some relevant code in your attached example.

Answer (score 1):

Your image must be in png format see the code below.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{

MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];
if (!pinView) {
   pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"] autorelease];
   pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];
   pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
 }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code. But once I pinch/zoom in or out that image remains same. I want an image to be the part of map.

Comment: I am not able to get you. which kind of image are you using ? Are you pinch/zoom on map ?

Comment: I want to add an image as a part of map. Same as location.

Answer (score 1):

This is working code and i already done with below code no necessory image is .png , .jpg or .gif its any formate you can use it

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
           MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
           NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
           pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
                            if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
                                pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

           pinAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_postoffice.png"];
           pinAnnotation.annotation = annotation;
           pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
           UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];



          [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;





       // now you can set diff image by  [annotation title] you  can set diff image with if else condition like below code


        if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:objAppDelegate.OfficePinTitle]) 
         {   

                        pinAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_postoffice.png"];
                        pinAnnotation.annotation = annotation;
                        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
                        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

                        infoButton addTarget:self
                                                       action:@selector(showDetails)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                                        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

         }
         else
         {

                        pinAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_red_postoffice.png"];
                        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
                        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

                        [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                         pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
         }


}
```